# Why two independent sample t-test and two-way ANOVA give different results on same data set?

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I have two samples of data collected under two different treatments:

```
sam.a <- c( 0.1333333, 0.2258065, 0.1944444, 0.2894737)
sam.b <- c(0.137931, 0.093750, 0, 0)
```

I first tried t.test in R:

```
t.test(sam.a,sam.b)
```

which gave me result as below `(p < 0.05)`:

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  sam.a and sam.b
t = -4.1497, df = 5.8602, p-value = 0.006329
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.27151717 -0.06935361
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.1994576 0.3698930
```

When I tried the same data using anova in R:

```
aov(sam.a ~ sam.b)
```

The results became insignificant (`p > 0.05`):

```
            Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
sam.b        1 0.005970 0.005970   1.778  0.314
Residuals    2 0.006714 0.003357
```

Can someone solve this problem for me? Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do the equivalent ANOVA you have to set it up differently.

```
t.test(sam.a,sam.b, var.equal = TRUE)$p.value
#[1] 0.01819264
```

You need to construct a variable, which describes to which vector a value belongs:

```
samples <- c(sam.a, sam.b)
fac <- c(rep("a", length(sam.a)),
         rep("b", length(sam.b)))

summary(aov(samples ~ fac))[[1]]$"Pr(>F)"[1]
#[1] 0.01819264
```

You used `samp.a` as the dependent and `samp.b` as the independent and basically did a regression between them, which is not the same at all. (Note that `aov` internally always does OLS regression and calculates the relevant sums of squares from the regression result.)

If you assume unequal variances in the t-test (as the default does) and do a Welch test, standard ANOVA won't reproduce the p-value exactly.